# Varray compare item in the collections

Tags: sql, oracle

The a table of movies with attribute of directors and actors. The actor is a varray type of actor_type contain 5 actor. i want to retrieve the movie that actor is both director and actor.

i tried

```
select actors, title, director
from movie
where actors = director
```

it telling me inconsistent datatype

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Why does `actor_type` contain actors? A test script showing the problem would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t provide the sample data so my understanding from your description is:

The director and actor attribute are in the movie table and the actor is displayed as Varray, which being called actor_type. Also, the actor Varray contains 5 actors in each movie.

The way to query Varray is different, you can use TABLE expression in FROM clause.

This website might help you

Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ00204

Then, you have to loop through the actor list and use the EXISTS or IN operator to check if the director is inside the actor list instead of using actors=director

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what datatype the director column is. You can do a convert on the join actor = convert(director). 
But I highly recommend you don't do this.

The problem with joining on strings is it is very inconsistent and if this is your only option to join actor to director, you need to restructure your tables.

I advise you have a Person table which contains both actors and directors.
You then need a table for movies and have the director and actor as foreign keys.

If the movie can have more than one actor, for instance, you then need a link table between person and movie tables (Same with the director if you have more than one director)

Hope this helps.